# Unable to quickly retag a question with few privileges

Tags: feature-request, tags, suggested-edits

I have few privilege so when I want to retag a question I have to request an edit, only changing the tags.

But when submitting the edition, I often have one of these error messages:

> - **Your post does not have much context to explain the code sections;
>   please explain your scenario more clearly.**
> - **Your post appears to contain code that is not properly formatted as
>   code. Please indent all code by 4 spaces using the code toolbar button
>   or the CTRL+K keyboard shortcut. For more editing help, click the [?]
>   toolbar icon.**

I only want to retag and have no time to reformulate the context of the question (and I actually retag because the question have nothing to do with the tag I was looking for, therefore I don't have knowledge on the subject.).

I think one of the following would resolve the problem :

- A "request for retag" link for low-privilege users
- Validation is skipped when editing tags only

**Edit**: Examples of some questions that shouldn't have the cascading tag and cannot be edited because of the validation:

- [JPA: Reverse cascading delete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1174939/jpa-reverse-cascading-delete)
- [MySQL ON UPDATE/ON DELETE CASCADE not CASCADEing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8160844/mysql-on-update-on-delete-cascade-not-cascadeing)
- [Is it possible to to cascade overloaded extraction operator with overloaded arithmetic operators?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4909399/is-it-possible-to-to-cascade-overloaded-extraction-operator-with-overloaded-arit)

Comment: Can you link to any of the questions that cause these errors?

Comment: Well, the real issue here is how did questions that didn't pass our minimum standards ever get posted in the first place? You shouldn't ever be locked into fixing these things in an edit because they shouldn't have been allowed to ever appear on the site!

Comment: @CodyGray It's generally on old posts that were written before those checks existed

Comment: Good job cleaning up the tags, by the way. :)

Comment: +1 for "Validation is skipped when editing tags only", I think retagging should be treated as a minor edit (don't bump to front page, don't perform validation checks).

Comment: @darvids0n: Minor edit, eh? Does that mean it shouldn't accumulate reputation as well? An edit is an edit. Tags are still important to a question, and not bumping it to the front page so other people can see the changes just allows tag changes to slip through the cracks and allow for abuse.

Comment: You can only retag at 500 rep, and the system has some automated checks in place. That's about as far as we can go towards preventing abuse (although maybe raise the rep required for retagging to 1k? though I'm not sold on that). Plus, anyone following the tag it's moved to will see it bumped still, and those should be exactly the people who will know if it was retagged incorrectly.

Answer (score 2):

Your first feature already exists. You gain the privilege to [retag questions](https://stackoverflow.com/privileges/retag-questions) (without editing the body) at 500 reputation, so why not go post some questions and/or answers and build up some reputation so you can access the feature?

As a low-rep user, you are restricted to these things, and I honestly don't see them adding exceptions *just* for low-rep users. If you're not willing to fix other problems in the post, then leave it for someone else to fix or go to a chat room and point it out to someone. You had time to come type out this question on meta, which probably took longer than it took me to reformat the code in those questions properly.

Comment: There's already a "request for edit" option, available for any logged-in users, a "retag" privilege for 500 rep. and an "edit" for 1000 rep. It would make sense to have a "request for retag" privilege for under 500 rep.

Comment: Retag as a separate privilege [has been removed.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/182586/do-we-still-need-the-retag-privilege)