# Does retagging the question need peer reviews?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, tags, review

As far as I know if a user has crossed 500 rep, he can retag the questions and it doesn't go through peer review.

But when I retagged [this question on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17416735/how-to-get-the-the-sum-using-variable-sql), it did go through peer review and I even got 2 rep points. Has this been changed recently? The new [privileges](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges) page doesn't mention anything about this retagging.

Comment: The retag privilege [has been destroyed](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/186373/propose-a-privilege-to-sit-in-the-500-reputation-mark) (although I thought they would wait until they decided on a new privilege to replace it).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes - now that we have suggested edits and *anyone* can propose tag changes to a question, [the re-tag privilege has been retired](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/186373/propose-a-privilege-to-sit-in-the-500-reputation-mark). We're in search of a new privilege to take its place, but the change is live. We'll be getting something in that spot in the very near future.

This means that changes that *just* edit tags are okay, but do have a look at the post to see if anything besides tags might need fixing. If you were previously making tag changes that weren't rolled back, then you'll very likely have no problem getting them in. In fact, people with far less than 500 reputation have been re-tagging questions for quite some time now.

We really did hope to have something to replace the privilege prior to retiring it, but the change needed to go out and we can still get something (hopefully more substantial than just being able to edit tags, which anyone can effectively do) in its place rather soon.

Comment: [Why remove a useful feature?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/182586/do-we-still-need-the-retag-privilege/186390#186390)

Comment: Please update [Recent feature changes to Stack Exchange](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/59445)

Comment: And now that retagging priviledge is gone, retag only edits [get rejected as being too minor](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/2437256). Happy?

Comment: It would be good to publicise, e.g. through the blog. I wasted a lot of time just now finding out what had happened to my ability to retag (I used to do this as a matter of course, don't need to get rep for it).