# What is the suggested edit review policy for tag-only edits now?

Tags: discussion, tags, review, suggested-edits, privileges

Now that the [Retag privilege is no more](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/182586/do-we-still-need-the-retag-privilege), I've been seeing tag-only suggested edits from 1500-rep users.

For example, one had the summary of '*burninating [tagThatWasRemoved]*'.

It's very tempting to reject these as Too Minor, but I know that these users used to have a Retag privilege (and are obviously trying to participate in a burnination.)

What should we do for tag-only edits from high(er) rep users?

Comment: Rejecting these from users that are participating in tag cleanups will very likely just make them completely give up. It was the one good use for it prior to removal.

Comment: As one such sub-2000 (not 1500) reputation user, is it even helpful for me to make tag-only suggested edits? Am I just creating work for moderators? I recently made a number of tag-only edits to fix questions that were tagged [unity] (the dependency injection system) when they should have been tagged [unity3d] (the game engine). I know a lot about Unity 3D and so I can quickly spot these mis-tagged questions to get them into the right searches. Should I also be looking to make other improvements to the questions at the same time?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Improve, improve, improve.

Or, just accept.

We want to encourage users to help clean up the site, and rejecting these as "too minor" quite obviously wouldn't achieve that. You have two options: Improve, or accept.

The preferred choice is obviously to improve the post. That much should be apparent. However, if you're feeling particularly lazy, then simply accepting the edit is okay too - though much less preferred.

If you see a user making dozens of retags without improving the post, feel free to ping the user and kindly ask that they search for things to improve.

Comment: I'm pretty sure I have this right, but I'd like clarification: I can just ping the user on one of the post they suggested an edit on, right?

Comment: @Undo If the edit was approved, you can ping the editor directly. That, or you can find one of their posts and ping them there.

Comment: You can't ping them from a post they have a rejected edit on?

Comment: [Not as far as I can tell](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/43020/206222).