# How many suggested edits in a day is too many?

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits

There is currently a user doing a large number of retags, and has currently suggested over 100 tag edits in the last few hours (about one every 30-45 seconds).

I appreciate enthusiasm, and correctly tagging things, but isn't this going a bit overboard?

Assuming the edits are *all* valid, is it really such a good idea to allow this?  For one thing, it's annoying to have a stream of questions all bumped up to the top of the Active queue for over an hour, and the Suggested Edit queue has been sitting at 40+ items for the same time period, but is it really hurting anything either?

Comment: I thought there is a daily limit of edits that can be suggested.  It could be worth considering lowering that limit.

Comment: @Servy - I thought there was too, but I can't find anything on it.

Comment: Wasn't there a limit of 30 edits per day?

Comment: This is too many. I just asked a discussion/feature-request to try to fix the larger problem [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/193244/can-we-have-a-new-mass-edits-review-queue).

Comment: Is this question related to this question: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/193025/213634? (Not flagging as duplicate just yet).

Comment: I assume you're talking about [Manas Mukherjee](http://stackoverflow.com/users/2140489/manas-mukherjee)'s edits to add [tag:quickbooks-online] and other related tags? [If only that user could do his edits without having to bother three reviewers each time…](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/182586/do-we-still-need-the-retag-privilege/186390#186390)

Comment: Or is it me?  I wouldn't assume my annihilation of [tutorials] would show up in a review queue.