# Should we lower the reputation threshold for question retagging?

Tags: feature-request, tags, rejected-edits, edit-ban

I recently attempted to add the [ambiguous-tag](/questions/tagged/ambiguous-tag) tag to several questions which discuss ambiguous tags, and it appears that I have been automatically banned from editing questions for this reason alone:

```
Too many of your edits were rejected, try again in seven days.
```

I'm surprised by the severity of this penalty: it appears that I have banned from editing questions for *an entire week* on account of a few unsuccessful retag requests.

Can we lower the reputation threshold for retagging so that this won't happen to anyone else in the future?

Comment: Did you review **why** we rejected the edits? You are adding a useless tag to posts that are all slated to be closed (no longer on-topic since the Meta.SO/Meta.SE split).

Comment: Had you slowed down a little, you could have reviewed wether or not your suggestions were being accepted *before* the ban kicked in.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Actually, I didn't see any inbox notifications about these edits at all. These messages didn't even show up in my inbox.

Comment: There are no such notifications. You'll have to watch [your suggested edit activity](http://meta.stackexchange.com/users/177227/anderson-green?tab=activity&sort=suggestions) if you want to monitor the decisions your suggestions receive.

Comment: @NickStauner Is a 7-day question ban a fair penalthy, then? In this case, did I receive a fair punishment for the mistake that I made?

Comment: It is the risk you take for making mass suggested edits, yes.

Comment: Meh. I'd call it an excuse to let someone else worry about editing for a while if it happened to me...I could probably stand to spend less time at it. Doesn't seem worth worrying about even enough to question it IMHO. I can't really relate to the words, "severity," "penalty," or "punishment." "Mistake" is fair enough, but given that this is all handled automatically, having the ban lifted without any human review in a week doesn't seem unfair to me...

Comment: I agree that the retag privilege should return (and voiced my opinion on the matter already when it was removed), but this case is actually the very reason we sometimes do need suggested edits, even for this kind of stuff.

Comment: Although @FEichinger hinted at it, no one has explicitly mentioned it.... there used to be a retag privilege, but [it was removed](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/182586/do-we-still-need-the-retag-privilege).

Answer (score 3):

> ...it appears that I have been automatically banned ... Can we lower the reputation threshold for retagging so that this won't happen to anyone else in the future?

I infer from this that when you wrote your question you didn't accept that what you'd done was wrong. Your later comments seem to show that you do realise and accept though.

The reputation threshold for tag edits should never be lowered from what it is.

The system is in place for a reason - it's not necessarily to protect the community from your one little mistake, it's to protect us from the hundreds who are way worse than you. You've learned your lesson, some out there never do.

Just chill for your 7 days off - it will be over before you know it.

Comment: Pretty sure what the asker did wasn't _wrong_ at all, at least not in any moral sense - it was just not all that useful given the circumstances.