# Will inline tag editing for 10k be removed?

Tags: support, privileges

[This meta post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/186373/202832) by a Stack Exchange employee says the following:

> [T]he retag privilege serves a lot more confusion and a lot less of
>   its benefit due to the suggested edit system. It must be done away
>   with. It *will* be done away with.

Does this mean that the [10k "Edit tags inline"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools) will be removed? Or is this another privilege of which I am not aware?

Comment: Why not get an additional 160 rep and try it out?

Comment: @Antony Working on it...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have misunderstood that remark. That line doesn't talk about *inline* tag editing. It talks about a privilege to edit *just* the tags without review, which was available at 500 points. Quoting the [original privilege description](http://web.archive.org/web/20130624084336/https://stackoverflow.com/privileges/retag-questions) (web archive link):

> When you receive this privilege you get the ability to retag posts without having to go through the peer review system. When you reach 2000 reputation, the retag button will disappear, since all of your edits will bypass the peer review system.

That feature is long since gone; the [original report](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/182586/do-we-still-need-the-retag-privilege) is marked as [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed).

The inline editor for tags is not going anywhere; it is *very* useful. It looks like this:

<kbd>[image: edit tags link]</kbd>

and when you click on it just the tag editor box appears:

<kbd>[image: edit tags widget]</kbd>